# Searching ActiveRecord by DateTime not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I asked a question regarding this yesterday, but it was muddled and didn't make sense, so I'm going to boil it down to the core issue.

I have an `entries` table. When a new record is saved, the `entries_controller` adds a time to the `date` column, which is recorded as a datetime. In the `new` method, I declare a new DateTime as so:

```
@entry.date = DateTime.new( params[:year].to_i, params[:month].to_i, params[:day].to_i )
```

I then include it as a hidden field with formtastic:

```
<%= f.input :date, :as => :hidden %>
```

Once the entry is saved to the database, the date field looks like `2011-02-10 00:00:00`. Everything is working as planned so far, but when I try to retrieve that entry by querying against the `date` field, I get `nil`.

I've tried:

```
search_date = DateTime.new(2011,2,10)
Entry.find_by_date(search_date)
=> nil
```

I've even tried to search by string, which doesn't make sense since it's a datetime field.

```
search_time = '2010-02-10 00:00:00'
Entry.find_by_date(search_date)
=> nil
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why can't I retrieve the record by date?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
Entry.where("date = #{search_date}")
```

Comment: Nope. That threw a ton of errors as is, and changing it to: `Entry.where("date = '#{search_date}'")` returned nil

Comment: Weird, cause i tested it in my own application and seemed to work fine. Can you print the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in `Rails 3.0.4`, `mysql2 0.2.6` and

```
Entry.find_by_date(DateTime.new(2011,2,10))
```

works.

Having said that, why are you using a datetime column to save a date?  Other than it just being a bad idea, you possibly could be running into some kind of timezone issues based on your rails and sql settings.  Some automatic timezone conversion could explain the behaviour you are observing but that's just a guess.  Please check the development server logs to see if rails is indeed generating the query you wish it to generate.

Comment: It is producing the correct SQL. I've changed it so the database records a date_token string now, which I thought was an odd work-around, but it seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: So this then is a database issue. That is indeed an odd work around but whatever floats your  db server's boat...  Rails appears to be doing it's job just fine.